# Preview: offset when moving in page history

Tags: preview

When I view a PDF file in preview and use the `Page History` buttons in the toolbar, preview doesn't jump back to exact same position I was previously, but adds a negative offset of about half a page.

I'm using preview on macOS High Sierra. Preview of macOS Sierra shows the same behaviour but Yosemite jumps to the correct positions.

Any suggestions how I could fix this behaviour?

This question may be in connection with [Preview: display position of link targets](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308126/preview-display-position-of-link-targets).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not seen this behaviour since macOS Mojave. The issue is fixed.